# Permission Manage All X Depends On Permission Read All Y

Tags: permissions, ant

Using Ant Deployment. As the title says, when I deploy I get errors on my custom profiles:

```
profiles/Some.profile -- Error Permission Manage All Custom_Object__c depends on permission(s): Read All Contact.
```

If I look at the permissions for this profile through the browser I can see that, under Standard Object Permissions, that Contact has all rows selected.

Where is this "Read All" parameter?

Under "Contact Field-Level Security for profile" there are *some* fields that aren't enabled. So do I need to enable them all?!

*ETA:*

*The user license associated with this profile is "Force.com App Subscription"*

*In the sandbox org, Here's what I see from the Profile page:[image]*

*In the developer org, If I create a profile based on "Force.com App Subscription" I see this:*
[image]

*So in the sandbox View All is enabled, in the developer View All is disabled.*

Comment: Did you get any solution for it. I am also facing the same issue?

Comment: @chandan remove all object level permissions (modify all, read all, read, write etc.... ) from the link object.

Comment: Any insight into this error?  I'm getting the same thing.

Is it related to master-detail relationships?

Comment: @tggagne yes it's related to master detail. Basically, if you don't deploy permissions for the master object then you shouldn't deploy "view all" or "modify all" on the detail object, because that's not something you have control over.

Comment: @powlo - can you pls add as a answer. so that it'll be immediately visible

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a very similar issue with `Opportunity` and a custom object that had a Master-Detail relationship back to Opportunity.

I was attempting to insert an `ObjectPermissions` record against `Opportunity` for a particular ParentId PermissionSet and got the following error:

```
Id permissionSetId = //... Some existing Permission Set gets looked up. 

// Note the omission of PermissionsViewAllRecords = true
ObjectPermissions opportunityObjectReadPermission = new ObjectPermissions(SobjectType = 'Opportunity',
                                                        PermissionsCreate = false,
                                                        PermissionsDelete = false,
                                                        PermissionsEdit = false,
                                                        PermissionsRead = true
                                                    );
opportunityObjectReadPermission.ParentId = permissionSetId;
insert opportunityObjectReadPermission;
```

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, **Permission Read All ChildCustomObject__c depends on permission(s): Read All Opportunity**: []

It turned out there was already an `ObjectPermissions` record for `ChildCustomObject__c` that had `PermissionsViewAllRecords = true`. For that to exist there was already a corresponding `ObjectPermissions` for `Opportunity` with the same view all records setting. That makes sense:

**If you are going to allow the view all records permission on the detail object in a master-detail relationship you also need to grant it on the master object.**

This is applicable to your deployment issue as well. You can't deploy permissions for the child/detail sObject without also deploying the required permissions to the master sObject.